# SONAR - Status returned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [407]

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

While running sonar scanner against my project with sonarqube-7.9.4(configured with Java 11) I am getting below error but working perfectly fine with sonarqube-6.7.7(configured with Java 8).

Any help on this ?

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project : Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Status returned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch/index] is not valid: [407] -> [Help 1]

Comment: could you please add you sonar.properties file and sonar command ?

Comment: 407 is [Proxy Authentication Required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/407) error code. Are both server accessible in the same way? I mean proxy configuration, SSL configuration etc.

Comment: @DashrathMundkar - I am using default sonar.properties and no changes has been made to it. Command used - mvn sonar:sonar

Comment: @agabrys - I am trying this in my local. Yes, both sonarqube-6.7.7 & sonarqube-7.9.4 are running under same proxy configuration.